# How can I stop a python subprocess after a certain amount of time?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am grading python assignments in an entry level class and I run their programs with the same input as my sample program and compare the outputs:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, arg_path],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        universal_newlines=True,
                        bufsize=0)
for the_arg in arg_list:
    proc.stdin.write(f"{the_arg}\n")

sample_output = ""

for line in proc.stdout:
    sample_output += line
```

The problem is if they really mess up and their program is waiting for more input than I am sending, the program will hange forever when I try to read from proc.stdout.  I cannot find how, using subprocess.Popen, how to set time limit (like 10 seconds) after which I can kill the process. Since I have a wrapper that runs each student it's a real problem if one of them hangs on me.
TIA

I have tried proc.communitcate(timeout=10) and that just kills the process no matter what, even is everything is correct.

Comment: From the perspective of an OS it's impossible to tell if a process is "doing work" or waiting for more input on *stdin*. So I don't think it is possible to do what you would want. Consider using higher limit if it is common that this processes take longer than 10 seconds and review them manually if a timeout occurs.

Comment: The process will never take more than 10 seconds, but the timeout does not work as I understand it.  I'm fine with killing a process doing work after 10 seconds so the rest of the program can move on.